# How do I get the gene annotations as a text file from a genbank file?

Tags: gene, sequence-annotation

Also [posted on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9591298/)

I have a genbank file and I need the following details about the gene annotations in a text file

```
# ID    name    start   stop    frame   product description function    cogcats status_region   status_function type    region_number   function_number
```

How do I go about extracting them? Please let me know if more information is needed from me! Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) an example input genbank file and ii) the _exact_ output you would want from that example. Also tell us what operating system you are using so we know what tools you have available. Will this file describe a transcript? A gene? A chromosome? Most of the fields you mention aren't standard, so we really need the example to understand.

Comment: The fact that Genbank files are also text files, I believe you meant that you prefer the same data in the "table format". In that sense why not fetching your annotations of interest in GFF/GTF format? And if that is not available for your genome of interest, there are tools that convert Genbank to GFF. Seeing the column names in your example, I think you can go for the `GFF3` format and "expand" the last column (`attritubes`) to extract the semicolon-separated info within that column.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://www.biostars.org/p/9591298/